# Multi Tables on One Entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I've got three tables as the following example:

```
Table A
- ID (PK)
- ID_B
- ID_C
- Description

Table B
- ID (PK)
- Description

Table C
- ID (PK)
- Description
```

The ID's from `Table A` are not mapped as Foreign Key, but they are (And I Can't change that), how can I map them in only one entity?
I tried `SecondaryTable` but it request me to use the PK of the `Table A` with the PK of `Table B`, I tried to reference another field of the table but I wasn't able to do it.

Anybody can help me?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: did you tried this answer ? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283919/is-possible-map-a-single-entity-with-multiple-tables-using-jpa

Comment: Yes i Did, but in this solution, Table A,B, C got the Same ID/Field as primary key in all tables, in my case they're not the same field.

Comment: and with table inheritance ? 1 Abstract entity and 3 child classes maybe ?

Comment: This I Didn't, I'll do a little research and answer here latter, thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997203/jpa-how-to-use-the-same-class-entity-to-map-different-tables

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I can use it...I need to code everything on one entity only...

Comment: answer is simple. you can't.

Answer (score 0):

If you could define a view with appropriate join clauses, you could define an entity corresponding to the view and treat it as if it were a table.